# jQuery UI sortable revert: Reverting to the top left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

If you take the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/99yVq/2/ and drag one of the top portlets and drop into the top of the black area (representing a menu), it reverts to the top left before snapping into position. I'm presuming this is related to my method of animation (showing and hiding an invisible placeholder) as when I remove the .show and .hide revert functions as expected.

.sortable call:

```
$( ".content" ).sortable({
    handle: '.portlet-header',
    items: '>:not(.fixed)',
    revert: true,
    start: function(e, ui){
                    $(ui.placeholder).hide(300);
                },
                change: function(e,ui) {
                    $(ui.placeholder).show(300);
                }
  });
    $( ".content" ).disableSelection();
```

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Thanks in advance.

*Edit* They also do it if you drag them way off to the right, or onto the fixed portlet. also stripped down the test case.

*Update for Answer*

Taking into account the answer below I have updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99yVq/3/) using .animate and setting the widths rather than hiding the placeholder. The animation is not quite as rugged but it's good enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item you want to sort is appended to the placeholder (if set). As you are hiding the placeholder, theres no display style left and the item is appended to the body instead. If you want to keep the placeholder but want to "hide" it, think about styling it that way - with keeping it as a block element.

```
start: function (e, ui) {
  $(ui.placeholder).css('width', 0);
},
change: function (e, ui) {
  $(ui.placeholder).css('width', auto);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was just looking into this and presumed the case you mentioned was true. I was looking at 're-inflating' the placeholder in the 'stop' event but your solution may be cleaner. Using .animate instead of .css allows me to keep the effect (storing the original width externally).